# How to make a swift get query to specific url

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to swift programming and need sam help. I want to know how I can make a get query to specific url and save the response data to variable. I am sorry that I can't show you the url but its a company secret. I can tell you that the response I a json. I really need help and I am going to be very happy if some helps me. If I am not explaining well, this is my first stack overflow account, just ask me for more info.

Comment: Please check out this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3244963-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: this is not helping me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand that you have to make a GET call to a URL (apiREST), this gives you back a JSON in response, well, there are many solutions, if you are not very practical I can report you a library simple to use and especially free => https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire easy to integrate via Pod. Or even more basic and therefore easy to understand => https://github.com/sean7512/RestEssentials then of course you could opt to manually create a class that handles your requests, and turn the return data of the call in a JSON using the structs making them comply with the protocol Decodable...

Answer (score -1):

The code below fetches a JSON from the server through an HTTP GET Request and parses it into our ToDo model.

```
struct ToDo: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let userId: Int
    let title: String
    let completed: Bool
}

class ToDoService {
    func fetchData() {
        // Create the url with your endpoint
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1") else {
            return
        }

        // Create dataTask using the session object to request data from the server
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url) as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            do {
                // Parse the json object from the data fetched from the server into our model
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ToDo.self, from: data)
                print(response)
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}

let serviceApi = ToDoService()
serviceApi.fetchData()
```

Please consider handling all the error scenarios in the way you need.

**Result:**

```
ToDo(id: 1, userId: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false)
```